# Nginx - Cant fin index.php if not under / (root) location

Tags: php, nginx

I have trouble to run davical (php) web calendar. There is no errol log in nginx error logs. When is calendar under \ location everything work. But when i have calendar under /calendar location. it returns 404.

default server root is:  /usr/share/nginx/html/default

calendar index.php path: /usr/share/nginx/html/calendar/davical/htdocs\index.php

os: Centos 7

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name my_domain_name;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

## Https

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name my_domain_name;

    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/tls/certs/nginx/certificate.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/tls/certs/nginx/privatekey.pem";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_dhparam "/etc/pki/tls/certs/nginx/dhparam.pem";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate "/etc/pki/tls/certs/nginx/certificate.pem";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;includeSubdomains; preload";

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/default;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/php-fpm.conf;

    location /calendar {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/calendar/davical/htdocs;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

## php-fpm.conf

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME
    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your existing `location ~ \.php$` block serves the `/usr/share/nginx/html/default` root. You need a nested `location` to process PHP files under the `/calendar` URI.

Assuming that your calendar app is designed to work within a subfolder, this may work for you:

```
location ^~ /calendar {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/calendar/davical/htdocs;
    index index.php;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^ /calendar/index.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

Use the `^~` modifier to prevent the other `location ~ \.php$` block from taking precedence (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more). Use `$request_filename`, as it works with `alias`. Avoid using `try_files` with `alias` (see [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97)).